# convert multidimensional css to php array

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to convert this css to a php array but it seems because there is a multidimensional css it doesn't quite get parsed properly.

I have put the below to a sanbox for viewing http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e53fd35c73d4f5b0c67d0d3a1e5d2b97f58a86fb

Here is the php function to that uses regex

```
function parseCSS($css){

    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('/(.+?)\s?\{\s?(.+?)\s?\}/', $css, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] AS $i=>$original)
        foreach(explode(';', $matches[2][$i]) AS $attr)
                if (strlen($attr) > 0) // for missing semicolon on last element, which is legal
                {
                        // Explode on the CSS attributes defined
                        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr);
                        $results[$matches[1][$i]][trim($name)] = trim($value);
                }
    return $results;
}
```

Sample CSS string

```
$css = "@-webkit-keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation{0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);transform: rotate(-360deg);}}@keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation{0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);transform: rotate(-360deg);}}#el_Qlda4JMGnZ{fill: #1076bc;}#el_r3BhVadOaj{fill: #fff;}.cls-1{fill:#03143b;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}";
```

Here is the current ouput

```
Array
(
    [@-webkit-keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation] => Array
        (
            [0%{-webkit-transform] => rotate(0deg)
            [transform] => rotate(0deg)
        )

    [100%] => Array
        (
            [-webkit-transform] => rotate(-360deg)
            [transform] => rotate(-360deg)
        )

    [}@keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation] => Array
        (
            [0%{-webkit-transform] => rotate(0deg)
            [transform] => rotate(0deg)
        )

    [}#el_Qlda4JMGnZ] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #1076bc
        )

    [#el_r3BhVadOaj] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #fff
        )
    [.cls-1] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #03143b
        )

    [.cls-2] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #fff
        )

)
```

Here is the expected output

```
Array
(
    [@-webkit-keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation] => Array
        (
            [0%] => array
                (
                    [-webkit-transform] rotate(0deg)]
                    [transform] rotate(0deg)]
                )
            [100%] => Array
                (
                    [-webkit-transform] => rotate(-360deg)
                    [transform] => rotate(-360deg)
                )
        )

    [@keyframes el_Qlda4JMGnZ_J0Dx98qCd_Animation] => Array
        (
            [0%] => Array
                (
                    [-webkit-transform] => rotate(0deg)
                    [transform] => rotate(0deg)
                )
            [100%] => Array
                (
                    [-webkit-transform] => rotate(-360deg)
                    [transform] => rotate(-360deg)
                )
        )
    [#el_Qlda4JMGnZ] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #1076bc
        )

    [#el_r3BhVadOaj] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #fff
        )
    [.cls-1] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #03143b
        )

    [.cls-2] => Array
        (
            [fill] => #fff
        )
)
```

Comment: If you don't mind to write the algorithm your self you can use: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: i did try that library but when i print out `$cssDocument = $parser->parse();` it didnt show a proper php array, there was all kinds of stuff included.